# Trace of norm ideal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, trace, discriminant

Let $I$ be a fractional ideal of a real quadratic number field $K$ of discriminant $D$. I thought a little bit about traces of ideals and want to ask if the following is correct. I have a proof for the statement, but it confuses me a little bit why I want you to double check the statement:

Let $J:=II'=N(I)\mathcal O_K$. Then

$$\operatorname{tr}(J)
= \begin{cases}
2N(I) \mathbb Z,\quad & D \equiv 0 \pmod 4,\\
N(I) \mathbb Z,\quad & D \equiv 1 \pmod 4.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It seems right. Since $J = N(I)\mathcal O$ and $N(I)$ is an integer, you have $\mathrm{tr}(J) = N(I)\mathrm{tr}(\mathcal O)$. So your formula boils down to calculating the traces of elements in $\mathcal O$ in the two cases --- the first where $\mathcal O = \mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ for some $d$ and the second where $\mathcal O = \mathbf{Z}[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$. Is that what you did? (You didn't state your proof.)

Comment: @tkr $N(I)$ is a positive rational number but not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I don't think I saw $I$ was just assumed a fractional ideal. But the rational vs. integer issue is irrelevant to my argument. All I was using was the linear nature of the trace map. No?

Comment: @tkr You are totally right, the argument works in both cases. My proof was much more complicated (I used a lemma which I proved some time ago which helps to compute $\operatorname{tr}(I)$ for arbitrary $I$ in terms of its prime ideal decomposition). Your proof is very clear and simple. Thank you a lot!